# Correct way of dispatching actions (Conditionally) while fetching data in background in react/redux app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Currently while fetching data in my react app, I'm using a property `isFetching` from redux store to show a spinner . The `isFetching` property is updated by dispatching 3 actions.

```
This is how the reducer looks
=============================

const posts = (state = {}, {type, payload}) => {
  switch(type) {
    case FETCH_POSTS: return Object.assign({}, state, { isFetching: true });
    case FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS: return Object.assign({}, state, { isFetching: false });
    case FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE: return Object.assign({}, state, { isFetching: false });
    default: return state;
  }
}

This is how the action creator looks
====================================

const fetchPosts = ({ shouldFetchInBackground }) => dispatch => {
  !shouldFetchInBackground && dispatch({ type: FETCH_POSTS });

  fetchUserPosts()
    .then(() => {
      dispatch({ type: FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS });
    })
    .catch(() => {
      !shouldFetchInBackground && dispatch({ type: FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE });
    });
}
```

What I'm doing here is passing a flag `shouldFetchInBackground` from a component to tell the action creator not to dispatch the `FETCH_POSTS` and `FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE` actions (I'm also not concerned with showing the error as the fetching is done in background), this way spinner won't be shown.

Now my only concern is if this is the correct way to do it or I should let the action creator send all the actions and handle the showing/hiding of spinner in the component itself (by using component state).

Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: handle the showing/hiding of spinner in the component . using HOC

Answer (score 0):

Handling the showing and hiding of spinner with redux state isFetching is a completely fine pattern. Here's one example.

```
export const handleFetchTodos = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: FETCHING_TODOS });
  try {
    const response = await api.fetchTodos();
    dispatch({ type: FETCHING_TODOS_SUCCESS, todos: response });
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({ type: FETCHING_TODOS_ERROR, error: e.message });
  }
};

const initialState = {
  isFetching: false,
  error: "",
  todos: []
};

const todoAppReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCHING_TODOS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true
      };
    case FETCHING_TODOS_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        error: action.error
      };
    case FETCHING_TODOS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        error: "",
        todos: action.todos
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. But my actual concern is if it's correct that the component tells the action creator not to dispatch a particular action while fetching in the background.

Comment: Yes, I don't see any problem.

Comment: Reducers should be pure functions but thunks could be inpure.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that the thunks could be impure but is it correct for a UI component to tell the thunk which action to dispatch and which not to?

Comment: I think so? Like a button dispatching an action is a UI to thunk. Or a text input maintained by react state passed to thunk could determine which action to dispatch?

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with my Lead, I came to a conclusion that the right way to fetch something in background is to let the action-creator
dispatch all the actions (FETCH_POSTS, FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS, FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE) and handle the showing/hiding of the spinner
in the component itself (like using a flag shouldFetchInBackground in component state).

**How I came to this conclusion?**
Well Redux depends on the principle of **single-source-of-truth** and we have isFetching flag in the store which tells that the app is
fetching the data. But when we stop the action-creator from sending the FETCH_POSTS action, it won't update the store and
isFetching flag in store will be false but we are actually fetching something. That contradicts the concept single-source-od-truth.
So the the correct way is to let the action-creator dispatch all the actions so that the store tells us correctly that something
is being fetched.

Hope this helps. Thanks.